# Why isn't a transform_view a borrowed_range?

Tags: c++, std-ranges

For std::ranges, why isn't a transform_view a borrowed_range? Here is a simple example: https://godbolt.org/z/14K8Y1xMe and below:

```
#include <ranges>

void foo() {
    auto i = std::ranges::views::iota(10);
    auto t = i | std::ranges::views::transform([](auto v) {return v;});
    static_assert(std::ranges::borrowed_range<decltype(i)>);
    static_assert(std::ranges::borrowed_range<decltype(t)>);
}
```

I checked that the base is a borrowed range. Is there an issue with the function? The documentation doesn't say: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view.

Comment: I could use `enable_borrowed_range` to make the assertion true, but I am wondering why the library does not do it when the base is a borrowed_range.

Answer (score 5):

`transform_view` internally saves the callable as a member, and its iterator saves a pointer to `transform_view` for accessing the callable. So when `transform_view` is destroyed, the callable is also destroyed, which causes its iterator to access a dangling pointer.

That's why it's not `borrowed_range`.