Not every view is a borrowed_range, but is every borrowed_range a view?
view does not imply borrowed_range
For example transform_view is not a borrowed_range, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76789448/7806123
Does borrowed_range imply view?
As it is cheap to copy, does it imply that it is safe to take references of its elements?

The two are different concepts. For example, vector<int>& is a borrowed_range but not a view, but can be converted to a view via views::all(v).

Thanks. So is every borrowed_range also std::ranges::viewable_range ?

borrowed_range is not necessarily a view, it just means that the iterators' lifetime is not bound to that range variable, so that the iterators are still valid when the range variable is destroyed.
All lvalue range types model borrowed_range, such as vector<int>&, but it is obviously not a view. However, all lvalue ranges can be converted to view via ranges::ref_view{r}.
This does not mean that borrowed_range implies viewable_range, as the latter requires views::all(r) to be well-formed, which is not the case for lvalue move-only view ​​such as owning_view<vector<int>>&; an rvalue immovable range such as format_parse_context  could theoretically be a borrowed_range, but its immovability makes it never a viewable_range.

Why is s below a viewable_range and requires move for views::all(std::move(s)):
std::ranges::owning_view s(std::move(vec));
static_assert(!std::ranges::borrowed_range<decltype(s)>);
static_assert(std::ranges::viewable_range<decltype(s)>);
//auto v = std::views::all(s); // error
auto v = std::views::all(std::move(s)); // Ok

And a reference of it sr, allows the same and it is !viewable_range
auto& sr(s);
static_assert(!std::ranges::viewable_range<decltype(sr)>);
auto v = std::views::all(std::move(sr)); //ok
Code here: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/cK4b1f7oW
